# Trying to determine what the Next Machine Operation is for specific Part Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, lead

I’m working with a table that contains Part number, Order of Operation and Machine Operations.  The goal is to determine what the Next Machine Operation is for each part number.

I’m able to do that with this example.

```
SELECT MyTable.PARTNO ,
MyTable.PCOPT  -- Machine Op order of operation,
MyTable.MACHOP,
lead(MyTable.MACHOP) OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.PARTNO, ABS(MyTable.PCOPT))   
as      Nextmachop   
FROM    MyTable

--Results 
PARTNO    PCOPT MACHOP  Nextmachop
0123456     10  IST     70A
0123456     20  70A     INF
0123456     30  INF     60 
0123456     40  60      10C
0140244H    10  10C     30A
0140244H    20  30A     INF
0140244H    800 INF     60 
0140244H    810 60      DOC
```

My issue is when it comes to the Next different PARTNO it grabs that MACHOP as the Nextmachop when it should be NULL or not put anything in there.  I’m not sure how to code this to achieve that

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU7) (KB3162659) - 12.0.4459.0 (X64)   May 27 2016 15:33:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )

Answer (score 2):

You need `partition by`:

```
SELECT t.PARTNO ,
       t.PCOPT  -- Machine Op order of operation,
       t.MACHOP,
       lead(t.MACHOP) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PARTNO ORDER BY ABS(MyTable.PCOPT)) as Nextmachop   
FROM MyTable t
```

Comment: Thank you.  I’ve been beating my head against the wall for a few hours now.  This did the trick.                                                                  PARTNO         PCOPT MACHOP    Nextmachop
0123456           40 60               NULL
0140244H           10 10C              30A